# How Django handling long request in another request?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request, celery

Issue about django handling a long request(50sec) in another request(3sec).

I have a POST request will return some infomation for user, in this request will call another api in the same app and it will query database and generate pdf report then upload to s3, it will cost about 50sec.

How can I let first request return infomation to user and generate pdf api run in background?

I have done some research, found Celery may be can handle this task, is this recommend? or anyone have advice?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Celery would work. But an easier solution, would be to split your request into 2 parts. First part will result in the page shown to the user. 2nd part is called via AJAX from the 2nd page. Add a spinner and show an update when done. Check out HTMX as one great framework to make this easy (e.g. lazy loading)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is where you'd bring in a solution like [celery](https://docs.celeryq.dev/), [rq](https://github.com/rq/rq), or [huey](https://github.com/coleifer/huey).

In the backend you will use a server like [redis](https://github.com/redis/redis) which stores the state of the jobs you scheduled (and if they errored).

Of the 3 above, I highly recommend celery. It's been around longer and has better telemetry on services like sentry and Scout APM.

To get started, here's a link for [First steps with Django](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html?highlight=django%20model%20id%20model#using-celery-with-django) on celery documentation website and its [sample django project on GitHub](https://github.com/celery/celery/tree/master/examples/django/).

**Getting into the job mindset**

- Data is serialized

  This means that to transport data the content will be [pickled](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) or encoded in [json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)
- Pass object IDs / naïve data to scheduled functions

  - Good: `book_id` as a `str`, then look up `Book.objects.get(pk=book_id)` inside the scheduled function. Even if it means making a redundant query - it's at least fresh data you can rely on.
  - Dangerous: Passing an instance of a model (e.g. `book` of `Book` model) in job params. The task may simply error due to it not being serializable. Even *if* serialized, your data may be outdated or stale by the time the function runs.
- Save the task IDs so you can look up the state of the job: this makes it possible to pin down if a job is underway already.